# Display post on main page with thumbnail

Tags: posts, post-thumbnails, homepage

So I am trying to find the easiest way to make this automatic. 
http://49.lv/ - under the seperator line I need to display a link to a post. The only thing is - it must have a thumbnail and post name(Small description would be nice). And yes, this one post to display, should be controled with CMS.

Could some one please give me suggestions on this(I am new to WP)? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi, can you please specify which post do you want to show? How do you want to decide which post to show?

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a featured post plugin, you can either display that POST in the widget area or below the SEPARATOR line by using a template function. You can find many plugins to do this job at WordPress Plugin Repository. [Link](https://wordpress.org/plugins/tags/featured-posts)
Here are 2 plugins

1. [Display Features News on Front Page](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-frontpage-news/)
2. [Featured Post Content Slider](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-featured-content-slider/)